# Why is using the increment operator a bad practice according to Checkstyle?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have a code like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < someNumber; i++) {
// loop body
}
```

Checkstyle complains about the increment (IllegalTokenCheck).

Why is it a bad practice to use increment operator in a loop like this?

Comment: Increment there is the standard usage. Checkstyle just has a gigaton of checks, and not all of those are sane. Someone just decided that the increment operators can be confusing to newbies.

Comment: This rule will be changed in Checkstyle 6.8 to not complain about post increment/decrement operator anumore - please see my pull request: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/pull/1163